# Calculate Exponential Moving Average Crossover For Time Period Of 5 Minutes, 8 Hours and 24 Hours using Python

Tags: python

I have a Pandas data frame which contains OCHLV (open/close/high/low/volume) data for every 1 minute over a period of 24 hours. I need to calculate the exponential moving average of the data for 5 minutes, 8 hours and 24 hours, using 5 minute increments, in Python.  Here is my code, but I do not think I am doing it correctly.

```
def calculate_macd(data):
    # Calculate 5 minute EMA
    ewm_5min = data.close.ewm(span=5).mean()
    
    # Calculate 8 hour EMA
    ewm_8hr = data.close.ewm(span=8*60).mean()
    
    # Calculate 24 hour EMA
    ewm_24hr = data.close.ewm(span=24*60).mean()
    
    # Calculate EMA Crossover
    ema_crossover = ewm_5min - ewm_8hr + ewm_24hr

    # Calculate the MACD line
    macd =  ewm_5min - ewm_8hr

    # Calculate the signal line
    macd_signal = macd.ewm(span=24*60).mean()

    return macd, macd_signal
```

Here is a sample of the data in the form of JSON before I add it to my data frame.  The first item is the epoch (unix) timestamp -

```
{
"data": [
    [
        "1682435820",
        "1.7995",
        "1.7976",
        "1.7997",
        "1.7976",
        "2615.1898"
    ],
    [
        "1682435760",
        "1.8023",
        "1.8003",
        "1.8023",
        "1.8",
        "848.9903"
    ],
    [
        "1682435700",
        "1.8022",
        "1.8023",
        "1.8023",
        "1.8022",
        "248.1847"
    ],
    [
        "1682435640",
        "1.805",
        "1.8022",
        "1.805",
        "1.8022",
        "184.8299"
    ],
]
```

}